# Create a screenshot from a form when submitting with html2canvas

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, html2canvas

I try to create a screenshot from a form when submitting with html2canvas.
I use this code:

```
//Create Screen
var element = $("#formmain");
var getCanvas;
html2canvas(document.querySelector("#formmain")).then(canvas => {
    document.body.appendChild(canvas),
    save_img(canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg'))
});
```

save_img function:

```
function save_img(data){
    //ajax method.
    $.post('save_screen.php', {data: data}, function(res){
        //if the file saved properly, trigger a popup to the user.
        if(res != ''){
            yes = confirm('File saved in output folder, click ok to see it!');
            if(yes){
                location.href =document.URL+'temp/'+res+'.jpg';
            }
        }
        else{
            alert('something wrong');
        }
    });
}
```

It is creating a screenshot but the input form fields are allways empty
in screens.

Comment: please include the code for `save_img()`?

Comment: I have added it in my question. But the problem seems not to be the save_img function. Because the "document.body.appendChild(canvas)," also show empty input field.

Comment: So your funciton posts the screenshot data to `save_screen.php` then redirects? its not going to be adding any image data to your form. I would add `console.log(res)` and look in the developer console for hints.

Comment: Yes for test I put the image as copy under the #formmain ("document.body.appendChild(canvas),") but also in this canvas the input field from form is empty. But for example checkbox is working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
html2canvas(document.querySelector("#formmain"), {
       onrendered: function(canvas) {
       document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    },
});
```

Comment: onrendered is not working anymore I think it is depcreated

Answer (score 0):

I've got a working example of how to fetch it as text data.

The promise canvas object is streamed to text via the `toDataURL()` function

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://localhost/html2canvas.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

  <form id="capture">
    <input type="text" value="hello world">
  </form>

  <textarea id="target"></textarea>

  <script>
    html2canvas(document.getElementById("capture")).then(function(canvas){
      console.log(canvas);
      document.body.appendChild(canvas);
      document.getElementById('target').value = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/,'');
    });
  </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok I found the problem. The problem is, that I have an image on top of site. Without the image it work. You can see and test it here: https://liveweave.com/cJykDi

Comment: Yeah what I found is their example is pretty useless to just append the screenshot into the dom as a canvas element. You either need to send it for storage as a callback or add it to a field to the form as raw text.